# How to Combine two oracle QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a Sub query result
Which is

```
Select string_Agg(amount) from(select amount from Audit_comp where auditreqid=id)
```

it returns 300,500,700

and i need some all these using

```
select sum(amount) from(select amount from Audit_comp where auditreqid=id)
```

it returns 1500
but my requirement is i need a below result in a single cell

300+500+700=1500

Please Suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Select (list_agg(amount, '+') within group (order by amount)) || '=' || sum(amount)
from Audit_comp
where auditreqid = id;
```

If your version of Oracle doesn't have `list_agg()`, you can use your method:

```
Select replace(string_Agg(amount), ',', '+') || '=' || sum(amount)
from Audit_comp
where auditreqid = id
```

Comment: Can `list_agg()` be used without `within group (order by ))`

Comment: @Sick . . . I don't think so.